# How to evaluate function arguments with for loop

Tags: linux, shell, ash

I wan to parse my function arguments with the `for` loop

```
func() {
  for arg in $*; do
    echo "$arg"
  cone
}
```

This works fine if all my arguments are without spaces

```
func "111" "222" "333"
```

But it fails for args with spaces

```
func "111" "222 222" "333"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$*`, use `"$@"` instead:

```
for arg in "$@" ; do
     echo "$arg"
done
```

Explanation: Without double quotes, `$*` and `$@` are identical. Inside double quotes, though, they are different. See "Special parameters" in `man bash` for details:

> `*`      Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.   When  the  expansion  occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special  variable.   That is,  `"$*"`  is  equivalent to `"$1c$2c..."`, where `c` is the first character of the  value of the IFS variable.  If IFS is unset, the parameters  are  separated  by spaces.   If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>
> `@`      Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.   When  the  expansion occurs  within  double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2"` ...  If the double-quoted expansion  occurs  within  a  word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion  of  the  last  parameter  is joined  with  the last part of the original word.  When there are no positional parameters, `"$@"` and `$@` expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Answer (score 1):

Use this function with `"$@"` instead of unquoted `$*`:

```
func() { for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; done; }
```

Then call it as:

```
func "111" "222 222" "333"
111
222 222
333
```